# how to call method after send button is click while sending email from iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, email

I am sending email from iphone app i want that when user clicks send button of email after that it should call test() method any idea how to do this I am using following code.

```
NSString * emailBody =@"<html><body>Thank you for your participation in Consulting<br>Practitioner and Client Program.</br><br>Attached is the copy of your signed contract for your records<p>Please email or fax your completed W-9 form to<br>our PEI Support Team<br>Email:PEISupportServices@zoetis.com<br>Fax:800-741-1310<body></html>";



[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];





[self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];




}

}


 [self test];
```

}

Comment: test() - method .. In the sense ..? U need mail acknowledgement  or your own method..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to implemente this delegate method? It's called after the composer is exited by the user.

```
    - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error  {   
    NSString *message = @"";
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            message = @"Mail: canceled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            message = @"Mail: saved";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            message = @"Mail: sent";
//------- call your test method here 
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            message = @"Mail: failed";
            break;
        default:
            message = @"Mail: not sent";
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: how to call this method

Comment: It's a delegate method.So it will be call automatically.

Comment: This won't work on simulator.So try to use on device.

Comment: Add <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> in your .h class which will let you receive a callback in the following method for Cancel/Save/Sent/Failed emails sent through composer  - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error